# redux-form Multiple forms with the same name; how to not override syncErrors

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using `redux-form` to manage a wizard-like form. All the forms of the wizard steps have the same name, which was never really a problem, because they were never mounted at the same time.
Now, in one of those steps I have a modal, which opens another form with this name.

This leads to `redux-form` overriding the `syncErrors` property, when initializing the second from, so all the errors that were there before opening the modal are now lost.

**A quick example:**
I have a form with Field1 and Field2, both having errors. Now I open a modal with another form, which renders Field2 and Field3. The error of Field1 has now been removed from the state, even though it's still mounted in the background.

I'd think that the `keepDirtyOnReinitialize` & `enableReinitialize` props would circumvent this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is this the way `redux-form` is supposed to work? I know it's kinda weird, to have multiple forms with the same name, especially on the same page, but it made a lot of sense until now. Using a different name for the second form solves the problem obviously, but introduces a whole lot of other issues.

Any ideas? Do you think this is a bug?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `destroyOnUnmount` to false to keep the form fields and errors in your redux state.

Comment: Yea, I tried that. Doesn't really help here, because the first form isn't destroyed. Here is a codesandbox, if you want to see a minimal example: codesandbox.io/s/o547k8rqoz